# How to add audio media in a post?

Tags: posts, media, audio

I am **simply trying to add an audio file** in a wordpress blog!

I have tried different audio player plugins: the non-existing anymore (?) [haiku minimalist player](https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/haiku-minimalist-audio-player/), the [jQuery player](https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/html5-jquery-audio-player/), the [mb.miniAudioPlayer](https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-miniaudioplayer/) and [MediaElement.js](https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/media-element-html5-video-and-audio-player/).

I have had only one player installed in each attempt. And, for each of these, I can see the(ir) *settings* panel and add the respective code in some post to get the player displayed. So far so good.

I can't, however, add any media files in the player(s)!  All media files that I have uploaded, are nowhere to be selected. For example, while editing a post, I select *Add Media* and inside the *Insert Media* window, I expect at the very least to see the audio files (ogg, mp3 -- previously uploaded) under the *Media Collection* Tab.  This very "Insert Media" window is simply empty!

What can I do to trace the "error"? Is it, perhaps, related to any directory/file access permissions where WordPress is installed?

Comment: I have searched a lot, but I guess I missed the following thread: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/cant-add-media-to-pageproduct-with-wordpress-35

Comment: And does that question solve your issue?

Comment: @s_ha_dum I am on it... will reply (of course) once I am sure what the problem is/was. With the help of a friend, it seems that entering the audio media's url (in text mode) inside a post, it works (somehow?).  However, the "Insert Media" window is still empty... (shrug)!

Comment: I ended up using the [mb.miniAudioPlayer](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-miniaudioplayer/) player. I have no idea why (under Kubuntu 12.10 and within from Firefox, Konqueror, rekonq, Midori, Chromium) the player inside the post does **not** work (specifically: http://www.alexandris23.net/archives/982).  It works, however, in the audio media's own page (specifically: http://www.alexandris23.net/archives/982/sidebysidethomasdaskalou) from within Firefox & Midori (not the rest!).

Comment: Note, due to limited knowledge & very limited free-time, I have chosen to simply add a link, inside the post of interest, to the audio media's own page. Just in case before the questions "did you try that..." come-up.

Comment: A friend, however, confirmed that it works with Opera, and Chrome!